# Как получить значение data атрибута в чикле each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$.each($('.phones'), function(i, elem){
  console.log(elem.data('id'));
  // здесь выполнение какого то кода
  // ...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phones" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="phones" data-id="25"></div>
<div class="phones" data-id="47"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так думаю

```js
$.each($('.phones'), function(i, elem){
  console.log($(elem).attr('data-id'));
  // здесь выполнение какого то кода
  // ...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phones" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="phones" data-id="25"></div>
<div class="phones" data-id="47"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Он по сути `$(elem)` заменяет на `$('<div class="phones" data-id="2"></div>')` и тд, если посмотреть что в `console.log(elem)`

Comment: А на производительность не повлияет, если допустим будет несколько тысяч таких записей?

Comment: Все зависит от задач. Вот так вот на счёт производительности с наскоку не ответишь

Answer (score 2):

Оберните elem в jquery, иначе у вас не чего не выйдет, так как в данном примере идет чистый js

Для jQuery

```
console.log($(elem).data('id'));
```

Если использовать vanilla

```
console.log(elem.dataset.id);
```